# How to set timer per tab not array

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a code to switch between tabs. 
the timer is set to switch between all tabs. 
I would like to have the timer to be set per tab 
Example:

> tab 1 = 5 seconds tab 2 = 10 seconds tab 3 = 1 minute

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function(){
        var index = 0;
        var t = $('#tt');
        var tabs = t.tabs('tabs');
        setInterval(function(){
            t.tabs('select', tabs[index].panel('options').title);
            index++;
            if (index >= tabs.length){
                index = 0;
            }
        }, 10000);

    });


</script>



<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs">
<div title="1"></div>
<div title="2"></div>
<div title="3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You appear to be using an older version of jQuery and I do not see jQuery UI Library included.

Comment: which one should I use?

Comment: That is up to you. If you wish to use easyUI, that's fine. I would just not expect as much response from the tag `jquery-ui` since easyUI is very different that jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to apply this to your code. Here is a jQuery Tabs example. You basically need the timing element.

It was not clear if you needed it to Repeat or Stop. This example repeats and I included a way to stop it.

```js
$(function() {
  var s = [5, 10, 60];
  var c = 0;
  var tt = $("#tt").tabs({
    active: 0
  });
  var intr = setInterval(function() {
    // i = Current Active Tab Index
    var i = tt.tabs("option", "active");
    if (c == s[i]) {
      console.log("Switch", c);
      //Activate Next Tab
      tt.tabs("option", "active", ++i);
    }
    c++;
    if (c > s[s.length - 1]) {
      // Repeat
      tt.tabs("option", "active", 0);
      c = 0;
      // Stop
      // clearInterval(intr);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tt">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now we have an interval of 1 second (1000 ms) and we increment a Counter `c` each second. Once that matches the trigger times in our Array, we switch to the next tab. Once we've reached a point after the last element in the array, we repeat or stop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!